# sound-juicer is failing for me in 16.04 (see the cascade in the question)

Tags: 16.04, gstreamer, sound-juicer

I'm pretty sure I don't have enough information yet to solve this question, but sound-juicer has failed for me in a very specific way, which I'd like suggestions for how to debug, with the understanding that it may be a hardware problem (the disc in question, for example).

After hitting extract:

[image: "Could not open device for writing"]

But I am able to write other files from this disk. And from other disks, so why this file?

Hitting "Close":

[image: error starting ripping pipeline]

So, possibly data corruption? I've checked the disk, and it appears pristine.

Close again:

[image: GStreamer error: state change failed and some element failed to post a proper error message with the reason for the failure.]

?

None of the results at [a Google search for this string and sound-juicer](https://www.google.com/search?ei=BvqJWsS7O86gjwPEqI_IBg&q=%22GStreamer%20error%3A%20state%20change%20failed%20and%20some%20element%20failed%20to%20post%20a%20proper%20error%20message%20with%20the%20reason%20for%20the%20failure%22%20sound-juicer%20&oq=%22GStreamer%20error%3A%20state%20change%20failed%20and%20some%20element%20failed%20to%20post%20a%20proper%20error%20message%20with%20the%20reason%20for%20the%20failure%22%20sound-juicer%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3...0.0.1.274.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.O00U6o6hy7s) are relevant.  are useful.

How would I go about making it possible to debug this usefully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To further debug what is going on here, first step:

## Run sound-juicer from the command line

Try to get the bug to reproduce after you run it from the command line, and hopefully you will see more output show up in the terminal where you ran it.

```
# First open up 'gnome-terminal', then
$ sound-juicer
```

If that doesn't get you any more info...

## Check common log files

- General errors: `/var/log/syslog`
- Kernel/Hardware errors: run the command `dmesg`
- Kernel/Hardware errors: `/var/log/kern.log`

Next...

## Run sound-juicer from the command line with debug options

```
$ sound-juicer --help-all |grep -i debug
  --gdk-debug=FLAGS                 GDK debugging flags to set
  --gdk-no-debug=FLAGS              GDK debugging flags to unset
  --gtk-debug=FLAGS                 GTK+ debugging flags to set
  --gtk-no-debug=FLAGS              GTK+ debugging flags to unset
  --brasero-media-debug             Display debug statements on stdout for Brasero media library
  --gst-debug-help                  Print available debug categories and exit
  --gst-debug-level=LEVEL           Default debug level from 1 (only error) to 9 (anything) or 0 for no output
  --gst-debug=LIST                  Comma-separated list of category_name:level pairs to set specific levels for the individual categories. Example: GST_AUTOPLUG:5,GST_ELEMENT_*:3
  --gst-debug-no-color              Disable colored debugging output
  --gst-debug-color-mode            Changes coloring mode of the debug log. Possible modes: off, on, disable, auto, unix
  --gst-debug-disable               Disable debugging
```

Looking at that list and the text of the error pop up, I'd start with

```
$ sound-juicer --gst-debug=all
```

And proceed from there.  Once I reproduced it, perhaps with **all** the debug flags turned, on, and it was clear this was not a setup problem, or problem with something you did configuration-wise.  I would...

## File a bug on sound-juicer upstream

Look in [their bug tracker](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/page.cgi?id=browse.html&product=sound-juicer), and file away!   You can also file a [bug in launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sound-juicer/+filebug), but make sure to reference the upstream bug when you file.  You can also go the other way around and use `ubuntu-bug sound-juicer` which would make a nice first start in launchpad, but don't be shy and leave the issue there, inform the upstream devs of the issue too.

## More info

See here for some general tips on [running gtk apps with debug flags](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-running.html).